# "Not Writable! - Root.plist" greyed out when building

Tags: iphone, xcode

Was having a play with settings bundles just before in xcode 3.2.3 (sdk 4.0.1), but then I deleted the settings.bundle folder and 'also moved to trash'ed.

Now every time I build I have a dialogue "Save before building?" and the root.plist file there, but greyed out and unselectable.

I checked the directory where it was claiming to be, but nothing there.

Its getting annoying. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Xcode 4.x is still under NDA. Try the Apple Developer forum where we can contractually talk about unreleased software.

Comment: sorry, i mean iphone sdk 4.0.1 xcode version 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a bundle again and deleted it... fixed the bug